# kdiff3 merging result

Tags: comparison

is there any way to generate a text file with merge result.Thanks a lot!
Say a.txt looks like

```
1
2
```

b.txt like

```
1
3
```

and merge result output like below

```
1
<<2
>>3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

diff a.txt b.txt > diff.txt

Comment: OS: winXP. Is there any other way besides using diff (cygwin install needed). Thanks.

Comment: Powershell rocks and it runs on XP.  Have fun!